# INSERT INTO not working one table but works on others & update works too?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, php-mssql

My PHP/SQL script does **not** work on the **new table I cloned** but **works perfectly fine** on the **table I copied the new table from** using this:

```
SELECT * INTO slide FROM news
```

Here's my insert form:

```
<div class="the-form" style="width:100%;">
<form class="userTrans" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="act_userTrans" value="__insertNews_">
    <p>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="type">News Type:</label>
        <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="autor">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor">
    </p>

    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
    <p class="form-footer">
        <button class="button userTrans" style="background-color: #DB6D1D;">Publish News</button>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

And here's my edit form:

```
<div class="the-form" style="width:100%;">
<form class="userTrans" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="act_userTrans" value="__updateNews_">
    <p>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?=$edit[title]?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="type">News Type:</label>
        <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="<?=$edit[type]?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="autor">Author:</label>
        <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor" value="<?=$edit[autor]?>"/>
    </p>

        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$edit[id]?>">

    
    <p class="form-footer">
        <button class="button userTrans" style="background-color: #DB6D1D;">Publish News</button>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's my process for updating & inserting my two different forms:

```
    if($activity == "__insertNews_")
    {
        $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
        $autor = htmlspecialchars($_POST['autor']);
        $type = (int)$_POST['type'];
        if(empty($_POST['type']) || empty($_POST['autor']) || empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['text2']))
        {
            echo response(0,'Fill up all the forms.',0);
            exit();
        }
        //echo $_POST[text2];
        $news = mssql_query("INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.news (title,text,type,autor) VALUES ('$title','$_POST[text2]','$type','$autor') ");
        echo response(1,'Publishing '.$title.' success!',0);
    }
    
    if($activity == "__updateNews_")
    {
        $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
        $autor = htmlspecialchars($_POST['autor']);
        if(empty($_POST['autor']) || empty($_POST['title']))
        {
            echo response(0,'Fill up all the forms.',0);
            exit();
        }
        $news = mssql_query("UPDATE DB1.dbo.news set title='$title',autor='$autor' WHERE id='$id'  ");
        echo response(1,'Editing '.$title.' success!',0);
    }
```

So using those scripts above and i was able to INSERT & UPDATE any contents on **dbo.news**

However, when I change **DB1.dbo.news**  to the new table I created ( **DB1.dbo.slide** ) the "INSERT" won't work.

I tried to add data using the same form & processing script, the "INSERT" won't work on dbo.slide but when I test it on dbo.news I'm able to insert data. I also tested UPDATE, and it's working on **both** dbo.slide and dbo.news.

Now I'm wondering, why is it that the SAME script for INSERT is working on other table but it does not work on the new one (**dbo.slide**). It's literally confusing because I did not change any codes, I just changed the table I'm inserting the data into and the INSERT function stopped working.

What's the best way to debug this and find out what is causing this issue?

Comment: Two notes: 1) You are using old and unsupported PHP extension (`mssql_` functions). 2) To get information about the possible errors check the result from the `mssql_query()` call and get possible error information with `mssql_get_last_message()`.

Comment: `INSERT * INTO table FROM...` is not valid, it should be `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM...` or `INSERT INTO table(columns) SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: What are the `dbo.slide` and `dbo.news` tables definitions?

Comment: `$_POST[text2]` is strange. It should be `'$_POST[text2']` in the `INSERT` statement. And can you execute `mssql_get_last_message()` after the `mssql_query()` call and post the output? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Zhorov thank you for the time! I have to work on this old function because it is the currently and only available/compatible script for the game im working/playing around.

Comment: @Zhorov I tried using mssql_get_last_message() and i get this message when i use INSERT query on dbo.slider `The statement has been terminated` 
(the insert query only doesn't work on dbo.slider, it works on dbo.news)

I get this message:  `Changed database context to 'master'`  when i use INSERT query on dbo.news or whenever i use UPDATE query on dbo.slider & dbo.news (UPDATE query works on both tables, INSERT does not work on dbo.slider but works on normally on dbo.news.)

Comment: I also already tried removing the $_POST[text2] from the `INSERT` statement and just used this `INSERT INTO db1.dbo.slider (title) VALUES ('$title')` and still no luck making it work but when i tried the same statement/query on db1.dbo.news, i was able to insert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!** I deleted all the cloned database and used the **CREATE TABLE** statement to recreate everything including primary keys, constraint, etc and now its working!

It seems that i **shouldn't** be using this to clone tables

```
SELECT * INTO slide FROM news
```

Thank you everyone for taking the time to reply, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

mssql_query function no longer exist in newer php versions. i suggest you to work with PDO because one of it advantage for you is, **reduce the commonly used insert and update operations** and it's **safe against malicious attacks and through SQL injection**

But now, can't help you without `DB1.dbo.slide` columns and `DB1.dbo.slide` columns and your `DB1.dbo.slide` insert query.

So for main help, check `DB1.dbo.slide` columns and compare their with `DB1.dbo.news`. then rewrite your SQL query according to `DB1.dbo.slide` columns.

If your insert query worked for `DB1.dbo.news`, be sure your insert query for `DB1.dbo.slide` is not correct

Comment: I have to setting for this old mssql function for now because this is the only compatible script for the game i'm working/playing around. 

Btw, here are the columns of db1.dbo.slide 
`type(varchar(100),null)
title(varchar(100),null)
author(varchar(100),null)
p_img(varchar(100),null)
p_msg(text, null)
date(datetime, not null)
text(text,null)
pin(int,null)`

Those are also the same columns (100% the same) of db1.dbo.news because i just cloned the entire db1.dbo.slide from db1.dbo.news using this query: `SELECT * INTO slide FROM news`

Comment: About the insert query i used, i've posted it above already but here it is:
`mssql_query("INSERT INTO db1.dbo.slider (title,text,type,autor) VALUES ('$title','$_POST[text2]','$type','$autor') ");`

dbo.slide & dbo.news 100% have the same columns because i just cloned everything of dbo.slide from dbo.news  The issue is that, despite having the same column and using the same insert query, INSERTING data to the sql server only works on dbo.news because when i tried using the same INSERT query on dbo.slide, nothing happens. But the UPDATE query works on both tables (dbo.slide & dbo.news).